# Social mapping of contacts from computer communication information

Tags: microsoft, us7167910

This is a Microsoft Patent [us7167910](http://www.google.com/patents/us7167910) filed in 2002 and issued in 2007, when Web 2.0 was in its infancy. Is someone aware of similar work in the course of next 5/6 years from the issue date.

Answer (score 1):

You may have already looked at this but there are over a dozen patent documents that came after this and referred back to it. These cites are easy to see and follow on google patents which makes them into links. One example listed on the front of the Microsoft patent:

> US8234300 
>   Filed Oct 7, 2008
>   Issued Jul 31, 2012 
>   International Business Machines Corporation
>   Access to electronic social networks

[US 8234300](http://www.google.com/patents/US8234300)